# customising the symfony view.yml file

Tags: javascript, css, symfony1, yaml, symfony-1.4

I have a question regarding the view.yml file in Symfony. Basically I would like to be able to include certain javascript SDKs in my layout with the help of the view.yml file like so:

first i would add an entry the the corresponding view file:

```
all:
  load_facebook: true
  load_twitter: true
  stylesheets:    
  javascripts:
```

and then in the layout do something like:

```
<?php if (sfConfig::get('view_load_facebook', true)): ?>
          <div id="fb-root"></div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                appId: '<?php echo sfConfig::get('app_facebook_comment_app_id') ?>',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
              });
            };
            (function() {
              var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
              e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
              document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
          </script>          
<?php endif; ?>
```

Unfortunately I am unable to get the option with sfConfig::get('view_load_facebook') thus I'm guessing they have never been loaded.
Has anyone got something like this to work? I think it would be a very good idea to have this option in the view.yml file as it would be very easy implement and very flexible.

Thanks,

Vince

Answer (score 1):

You can store your custom settings in app.yml file:

```
all:
  load_facebook: true
  load_twitter: true
```

and refer to then with sfConfig::get(app_load_facebook)

Comment: @Vincent: I think this is the way to do it. Your current code is referring to the app.yml file already, with the "app" at the beginning of the configuration you're calling.

Comment: Yes, that would be an alternative however it is far too inflexible. I need to set the 3rd party sdk on a template basis or at least on a module basis. This would indeed also be possible in the app.yml file by holding an array of modules for which to enable the sdks however I feel that this approach is very unintuitive and not really the right place to put this information.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create an app.yml file inside the module directory? Anyway I don't know whether that would be a good solution.
Alternatively you may use slots.
Or maybe, even better, put all the code of the SDK in a JS file and insert that in the view.yml